# How to write unit test for a web page where user need to log in

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, express, mocha.js, chai

I'm writing unit tests for a page that users can only access after they have logged in. I have the following code to test whether the user has successfully logged in or not:

```
describe('login', function () {
    this.timeout(20000);
    it('should login with correct password', function (done) {
        this.timeout(20000);
        setTimeout(done, 20000);
        request.post('/login')
            .send({
                username:"admin@admin.com",
                password:"admin1"
            })
            .expect('Location','/profile')
            .end(done);
        });
    });
```

The test works and then I tried to add this code:

```
describe('secret page',function(){
    it('should get secret',function(done){
        request.get('/secret')
            .expect('Location','/secret')
            .end(done);
    });
});
```

I expect user should be able to get the secret page but I received an error:

```
GET /secret 302 0.424 ms - 28
Error: expected "Location" of "/secret", got "/login"
at Test._assertHeader (\node_modules\supertest\lib\test.js:247:12)
at Test._assertFunction (\node_modules\supertest\lib\test.js:281:11)
at Test.assert (\node_modules\supertest\lib\test.js:171:18)
at Server.assert (\node_modules\supertest\lib\test.js:131:12)
at emitCloseNT (net.js:1554:8)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:77:11)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
```

I tried to put the second "it" function into the first describe block, I get the same error. But when the website is running, a user can go to the secret page correctly rather than go back to login page.

Comment: Can you post the whole code ? What does the request do ? What do you mock ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to investigate how authorization works. Maybe you can grab some token from headers and use it later, just attaching correct header to your requests.

Another option might be using mocha's `beforeEach()` hook.